# Can the order of Keypress, Key Down and Keyup be manipulated

Tags: jquery

I confess to having completely confused myself reading various postings on the subject of event order and binding in jquery.

When testing I got some unexpected results.

As far as I can establish the order in which the event and corresponding handlers are executed is 1. KeyUp 2. KeyPress 3. keydown

This seems counter intuitive I was expecting keydown, keypress, keyup

I see various postings that reporting on how to order handlers bound to the same event but these are different events.

I expect that I am totally over complicating this. Could someone advise how I could ensure that keydown excutes before keypress before keyup.

Many thanks

I arrived at the order based on this snippet. I assume I have misunderstood in some way.

```
$("#middle_Name").keydown(function(event){
    alert("third is keydown");
}); 
$("#middle_Name").keypress(function(event){
    alert("first is keypress");
});
$("#middle_Name").keyup(function(event){
    alert("first is keyup");
});
```

Comment: The order **is** `keydown`, `keypress`, `keyup`.. can you show the code you're using?... and the answer to your second question is *no* (unless you use something messy like timeouts).

Comment: You (and neither jQuery) cannot change the order of native key event handler execution as they are fired through the physical action, e.g. pressing down or releasing the button on the keyboard.

Comment: here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/Db4N6/ @Matt is right

Comment: Many thanks to you all this is very helpful.